# Using a variable in a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture the last name, first name and number from a string that has the following pattern:

```
str = "Doe, John; 620 Eisenberg, Andrew; 253"
```

The following line of code seems to capture the last name and first name but returns None when I include the part for the number:

```
strfind = re.findall(r'(?P<last>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+), (?P<first>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+): (?P<num>\d+)', str, re.M|re.I)
print(strfind)
```

Sorry, could not get the Verbose version to cooperate.
I tried putting a comma and a colon outside the parentheses for **last** and **first** to include it in the search to capture the string that comes before it, but that didn't seem to work.  Along the same lines, I tried using a space at the end of the **num** group as well.

Excluding the **num** group I get the following output:

[('Doe', 'John'), ('Eisenberg', 'Andrew')]

Comment: Just change `:` to `;` after the last name.

Comment: I tried that, still getting None back

Comment: Yeah, as @Kasramvd said, `strfind = re.findall(r'(?P<last>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+), (?P<first>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+); (?P<num>\d+)', str, re.M|re.I)` should work (and it does work for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `:` with `;`, as @Kasramvd suggested, works perfectly:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Doe, John; 620 Eisenberg, Andrew; 253"
>>> re.findall(r'(?P<last>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+), (?P<first>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+); (?P<num>\d+)', s, re.M|re.I)
[('Doe', 'John', '620'), ('Eisenberg', 'Andrew', '253')]
```

If you want results in a list of dictionaries format, use [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and [`groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict):

```
>>> results = re.finditer(r'(?P<last>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+), (?P<first>[A-Z][A-Za-z]+); (?P<num>\d+)', s, re.M|re.I)
>>> [m.groupdict() for m in results]
[
  {'num': '620', 'last': 'Doe', 'first': 'John'}, 
  {'num': '253', 'last': 'Eisenberg', 'first': 'Andrew'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
>>> input = "Doe, John; 620 Eisenberg, Andrew; 253"
>>> import re
>>> tmpLst = re.split(r'[;,\s]\s*', input)
>>> print tmpLst
['Doe', 'John', '620', 'Eisenberg', 'Andrew', '253']
>>> output = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(tmpLst), 3):
...     output.append(tuple(tmpLst[i:i+3]))
... 
>>> print output
[('Doe', 'John', '620'), ('Eisenberg', 'Andrew', '253')]
```